# Is it possible for MAC OS X to check for older/newer versions of files before you copy files in finder?

Tags: mac, finder

I work with multiple users who edit files from our company server, which is too slow to work off directly. I copy files to my desktop to work on them, then move them back to the server, the file overwrites whatever was on the server, without prompting.

Is there a way to have OS X prompt if you are overwriting files, with details the dates of both files (The PC I worked on did this) so you know when both files were last modified?

Answer (score 1):

If a file already exists, OS X should be prompting you about overwriting it.  I've never run into an instance where this was not the case.  Since you are not being prompted, then something else is amiss and you should provide some more detail via editing your question or through comments. Any shortcuts you might be taking, keys you're holding down, etc.

That said, this isn't really a good way to operate. The modified date only tells you that the file changed, it can't help you identify WHAT changed, so you have to go through and make those changes directly.  Software developers solve this problem through [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) systems, but if you're working on Office documents or other proprietary formats, such a system might not work, or might be overly complex for your needs. Regardless, you're asking for data loss and/or headaches doing things that way, but without more details about the tools and the process, there's not much more advice that can be offered.

Answer (score 1):

If this is corporate stuff, you're going to want something a little more reliable than checking dates. I mean, you can do that with [any sync app out there](http://alternativeto.net/searchresult.aspx?search=sync), but why do that when you can use [git](http://git-scm.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Finder is notoriously bad at merging folders.

You could use [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/):

[image: transmit mac app]

Or Cyberduck:

[image: cyberduck mac app]

However [Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/) doesn't seem to display creation or modification dates:

[image: forklift mac app]

Or [Pathfinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/):

[image: pathfinder mac app]